# Is there a simple method for writing traces from multiple sbcl threads to standard output through MCLIDE/swank?

Tags: sbcl, swank

Using SBCL, I'm writing a small server and I would like to trace the server thread, but when I use mclide/swank, I do not see any output from the server thread.

? (require 'sb-posix)
NIL
? (sb-thread:make-thread (lambda () (format t "hi from the thread")))

?

When I try the same thing from sbcl directly, I see what I expect:

- (require 'sb-posix)
  ; loading system definition from
  ; /opt/local/var/macports/software/sbcl/1.0.39_0+html+threads/opt/local/lib/sbcl/sb-grovel/sb-grovel.asd
  ; into #
  ; registering # as SB-GROVEL
  ("SB-POSIX" "SB-GROVEL" "ASDF")
- (sb-thread:make-thread (lambda () (format t "hi from the thread")))
  hi from the thread#
  *

Does swank have issues capturing standard output from non-foreground threads? If I used slime, would this kind of thing work?